# Data grid view entry forms or any other solution for row and column wise entry form in window forms

Tags: c#

I want to make 2d type of entry form in window forms.if i take textbox then i have to make 130 fields.I want a simple solution of this type of entry forms.can, i make data grid view of this row and column wise entry or any other solution for normalize the database of if there 13 row wise fields and correspondence to that there are 10 fields in column wise

Comment: do you mean 13 rows and 10 columns ? Can you show me how do you retrieve your data ?

Comment: yes.I hav't made a database,i just want to know how can i make this in

Comment: es.I hav't made a database,i just want to know how can i make this in grid view by  using row header and column header and save values into mysql database